# using cimport in cython for numpy

Tags: python, numpy, cython

I am using `numpy` in `Cython` mostly by looking at examples on the net / SO:

```
cimport cython
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
from numpy cimport ndarray as ar
....
... = np.empty(...)
...
cdef ar[double, ndim=1, mode='c'] y = ....
...
... = np.argmax(...)
```

Suppose, now I make the change `cimport numpy as np` to `cimport numpy as cnp`. Then how do I know which functions (i.e. `np.empty`, `np.argmax`, etc.) in the code above rely on `np` versus which functions rely on `cnp` ?

Comment: First, try to see from where np is loaded, it should be overwritten to cython module as both of them having the same name .

Comment: i didn't quite understand. what do you mean by "try to see from where np is loaded" ?

Comment: print np.__file__. If it is from .so file or pyx, then cython module is the only one available and you can assume all of them relies on cython module.

Comment: aren't cython codes all compiled? if i try `cimport numpy as np` in an interactive mode it gives me an error.

Comment: either compile the code and run np.__file__ or use pyximport to compile it at runtime, but then you should put cimport statements in a seperate pyx file.

Comment: thanks, I did it. and then `np.__file__` shows me the `...numpy\\__init__.py`. now, how do i know if the `np.empty`, `np.argmax` in the cython code are using the `np` from `import numpy as np` or `cimport numpy as np` ?